# GitHub: Changes requested label stay after I answered all the code review questions

Tags: github

I'm a Pull Request owner (I have created this Pull Request / branch).
I asked my boss to review my code after I completed working on it and it passed the build tests.
The boss reviewed my code and requested several changes / asked several questions about my code changes.
I have changed the code and answered all the comments however "Changes requested" label still presented for this branch.
What did I miss?
(Sorry for such a simple question, I'm new with `GitHub` and I could not find answer for this problem in `GitHub` Helps.
[image]

Comment: if this public repo could you share a link?

Comment: Sorry, this is my company product repo. I can't.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reviewer who requested changes has to either "dismiss" the review or "approve" the change. You might think you addressed everything, but the reviewer might disagree ;-)

It'd be nice if there was a way to differentiate between "`<reviewer> requested changes`" and "`<reviewer> requested changes, and <submitter> updated the PR`", but there currently isn't any.

Answer (score 6):

Things have changed since the currently accepted answer.

Since February 2019 you can differentiate a little bit by "re-requesting" a review: https://github.blog/changelog/2019-02-21-re-request-review-on-a-pull-request/
This won't make the "changes requested" label go away, for reasons already explained by Mikeage. However, it will add a "pending reviewer" label making it clear what the current status of the PR is and notify the reviewer that it is their turn again in order to keep the process moving.

Answer (score 2):

Beside `re-requesting` mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110179/1266040

There some situation when you need merge without waiting for re-review (user what submitted request change is on leave, not responding, fix need to be merged)

So you can `dismiss review` to unblock pipeline:
[image: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/dismissing-a-pull-request-review]

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/dismissing-a-pull-request-review

Comment: Thank you for this answer. As you may understand, this question is no more relevant for me, but maybe it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Exactly - it was viewed 11k times so people looking at it.